# PHP PDO / Retrieving OUT Parameters from MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I need to retrieve the OUT Parameters from a MySQL Stored Procedure.  I can't find anything that explains this (and makes sense to me).

```
try {
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=db_name;host=localhost';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, 'usr_name', 'password');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL db.stprNewUser(:usrEmail,:newUserOK,:stprComment)");

$stmt->bindParam(':usrEmail', $tmpEmail, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':newUserOK', $newUserOK, PDO::PARAM_INT,1); 
$stmt->bindParam(':stprComment', $stprComment, PDO::PARAM_STR,100); 

$stmt->execute();

$outputArray = $dbh->query("select @newUserOK, @stprComment")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print "procedure returned [" . $outputArray['@newUserOK'] . $outputArray['@stprComment'] . "]\n";
```

I found the last two lines on another SO item, but it just returns NULL values.

Answer (score 4):

try this...
see if works...

```
try 
{
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=db_name;host=localhost';
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, 'usr_name', 'password');
} 
catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}


//$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL db.stprNewUser(:usrEmail,:newUserOK,:stprComment)");
//changed :newUserOK to @newUserOK
//changed :stprComment to @stprComment
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL db.stprNewUser(:usrEmail,@newUserOK,@stprComment);");

//declare only input parameters.
//good pratice put string length. assuming varchar(100).
$stmt->bindParam(':usrEmail', $tmpEmail, PDO::PARAM_STR,100); 

//dont need these
// $stmt->bindParam(':newUserOK', $newUserOK, PDO::PARAM_INT,1); 
// $stmt->bindParam(':stprComment', $stprComment, PDO::PARAM_STR,100); 

$stmt->execute();

$outputArray = $dbh->query("select @newUserOK, @stprComment;")->fetchAll();

foreach($outputArray as $row)
{
   "NewUserOk:" .  $row["@newUserOk"] . ", StprComment:" . $row["@stprComment"];
}

//$outputArray = $dbh->query("select @newUserOK, @stprComment")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//print "procedure returned [" . $outputArray['@newUserOK'] . $outputArray['@stprComment'] . "]\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using MySQL session variables, you can just use [bindParam()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

> `bool PDOStatement::bindParam ( mixed $parameter , mixed &$variable [, int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR [, int $length [, mixed
>   $driver_options ]]] )`
>
> Binds a PHP variable to a corresponding named or question mark
>   placeholder in the SQL statement that was used to prepare the
>   statement. Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as
>   a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that
>   PDOStatement::execute() is called.
>
> Most parameters are input parameters, that is, parameters that are
>   used in a read-only fashion to build up the query. Some drivers
>   support the invocation of stored procedures that return data as output
>   parameters, and some also as input/output parameters that both send in
>   data and are updated to receive it.

Don't forget to use the corresponding placeholders:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL superior_main_db.stprNewUser(:usrEmail, :newUserOK, :stprComment)");
```

Once you execute the statement, your variables will automatically contain the values you need.

Comment: The OP is asking how to use stored procedures, not how to bind parameters isn't he?

Comment: @vascowhite - Please read the question again. He's asking how to **retrieve** OUT parameters.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. He's already said he doesn't understand the manual though, so this isn't going to help without an example.

Comment: @vascowhite - I've made a little edit, let's see if its clearer now.

Comment: Still not getting the results of the output parameters. :-s

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve @newUserOK and @stprComment variables, just execute below query after calling stored procedure as below

```
SELECT @newUserOK, @stprComment
```

Comment: Amit, how do I execute the above query in the context of my current code?

Comment: Same as you execute other queries $stmt = $dbh->prepare ("SELECT @newUserOK, @stprComment");